# apt wants to remove essential packages after manual update of nvidia driver (Debian 11)

Tags: debian, apt, drivers, nvidia, dependencies

I needed the latest version of my nvidia driver to use OBS, so I decided to replace mine which was the official package. I downloaded the .run file from NVIDIA website and installed it, after removing the packages with `sudo apt remove nvidia*`. The previous version was 470 and the new one is 535.86.05.

After reboot, my system seems to work correctly. This time, I can start a stream with OBS, great. First thing off: Steam doesn't start this time and stays stuck on the loading window. Thinking some packages may be missing since my `apt remove`, I run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Bang: apt asks me to confirm the removal of many packages I need, without replacement: chromium, firefox-esr, libreoffice, pulseaudio, lxqt, xorg and more. Even stranger, these packages seem to work, I'm currently using Chromium to write this! So why?

Comment: because you removed one or more of the packages that these packages depend upon (or which depend upon other packages that depend upon the nvidia packages) and replaced them with non-packaged versions. apt only knows about packaged software, removing packages that lots of things depend upon (directly or indirectly) will trigger a cascade of other packages.  You can use the [equivs](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/equivs) package to make a dummy package that provides any needed dependencies, but you'd be better off reverting to the packaged drivers.

Comment: Also worth noting: installing the nvidia driver from nvidia's web site on a debian system is generally a very bad idea.  Mostly for the reason you've just discovered.   You'd be better off looking for an updated version in backports.debian.org, or just installing the newer driver from the latest stable or testing, or even from sid or experimental (but be careful - this may cause other packages to be upgraded to newer versions).

Comment: The same is true for most software - install packaged versions in preference to installing direct from the upstream's web site (second best is to download the source and build your own package.  or backport a package from a newer version of debian to your version.  only as a last resort should you even consider installing anything direct from upstream - app devs are great at their own programs but generally terrible at OS integration). I'd guess you just installed OBS studio from their web site, instead of debian's packaged version of OBS...if that's the case, then that was your first mistake.

Comment: [DontBreakDebian - Advice For New Users On Not Breaking Their Debian System](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian).   Finally, IMO your best option is to re-install the packaged nvidia drivers from buster, then upgrade debian to bullseye, then upgrade again to bookworm (which has nvidia 525.105.17)

Comment: The last link includes this: "Don't use GPU manufacturer install scripts".

Answer (score 0):

I should have followed the rule given [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_use_GPU_manufacturer_install_scripts): Don't use GPU manufacturer install scripts.

For my issue I just uninstalled everything, and installed everything back with apt.